# Jquery check if the 'select option' element has class 'treeroot' , if true : stop it from being selectable

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I check if the `select option` element has class 'treeroot' , if true : stop it from being selectable from the user?

```
<select  name="_groups_id_assign" size="1" class="valid">
    <optgroup label="Entité racine" style="display: none; ">
        <option value="6" class="treeroot" 
            title="Production - ">Production</option>//this one
        <option value="8" class="tree" 
            title="Production &gt; Accident du travail Agent - "
        >   »Accident du travail Agent</option>
        <option value="4" class="treeroot" 
            title="Production Automobile - "
        >Production  Automobile</option>//this one
        <option value="5" class="tree" 
            title="Production Automobile &gt; Automobile - "
        >   »Automobile</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: perhaps because you are not showing what you have tried so far in the JavaScript department in hopes to solve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("option.treerot").prop('disabled', true)
```

Users cannot select "disabled" options, but if the first option is disabled it will still appear in the dropdown when it is collapsed.